# USB Mouse custom driver

Tags: mouse, usb, driver

Is there a way I can create a USB Mouse driver for windows? I want to be able to plug in two mouses (or maybe 3, or 4) and interpret it's movement's and keypresses for an application I'm developing, in a way Windows won't even know there is more than a mouse plugged in.

Comment: You already *can* plug in two or more usb mice - do you want more than one **pointer**?

Comment: I want my application to be able to use another pointer. As if it whas a controller of sort, another input device.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP or newer should support multiple mice using Raw Input: http://www.jstookey.com/arcade/rawmouse/

Your application will need some code for drawing and handling its multiple pointers, but writing a custom mouse driver seems a lot more difficult to me...

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look at Mirosofts [Multipoint Mouse SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/).

It allows you to have upto 25 mouse pointers on the screen.

Comment: randomly imposed arbitrary limit ftw

Comment: Well how many mice would you be able to connect to a computer? And how would you show all the pointers.  Also how would you differentiate the cursors then?

Comment: Around 4 mice, I intend on using that for a game, so the pointers will show on different screens(sections).

Comment: MultiPoint is made in C#, so I have to use raw input :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645546%28VS.85%29.aspx
to be able to create a C++ application.
But I really don't know where to start.